# over/in in given context

Tags: prepositions

> I loved talking to him, but **over** the last year, he hasn't been very pleasant to talk to.

> I loved talking to him, but **in** the last year, he hasn't been very pleasant to talk to.

Are both sentences grammatically correct? Is there any difference between these sentences in terms of their meaning? I would probably use the first sentence myself, but I can't tell why.

Answer (score 1):

They both are grammatically fine.

You can also add in *during* which fits equally well.

I think *over* puts more emphasis on the number of interactions you had with him. You had many unpleasant conversations with him *throughout* the year. Whereas *in* doesn't make it clear - it might have been one unfriendly occurrence that saddened you.